# gcc doesn't merge consecutive fences

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-barriers, memory-model

For this simple piece of code

```
std::atomic_int i;
void foo() {
    i.store(1);
    i.store(2);
}
```

gcc generates the following assembly for ARM:

```
movw    r3, #:lower16:.LANCHOR0
movt    r3, #:upper16:.LANCHOR0
dmb ish
mov r1, #1
mov r2, #2
str r1, [r3]
dmb ish
dmb ish               ; why is this not eliminated?
str r2, [r3]
dmb ish
bx  lr
```

You may notice that there is a repeated fence generated in the middle, which seems to be superfluous. Is it an issue of gcc's optimizer being not able to catch and eliminate extra fences or am I missing something?

BTW, clang seems to handle adjacent fences.

Comment: Can you confirm what architecture and version of ARM (and GCC)?  Godbolt makes decent output for ARM64, but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: It's ARM32. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/BSPOKN

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does not, and I have been debating it for a while with various people. For external observer like myself effect is that it treats `atomic` as `volatile`, while standard doesn't require it to. I was not able to find a requirement for this in the standard.

However, it might also be a simple case of missing optimization.